# XSL disable-output-escaping not working

Tags: html, xslt

I am pulling a parameter from the database

```
<xsl:param name="theMessage"></xsl:param>
```

The data that is pulled html like below:

```
<style type="text/css">#container {width:100%; margin-top:20px; text-align:center; font-family: Verdana, arial; font-size:100%; font-weight:normal; }</style><div id="container"><b>Text here</b></div>
```

The XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$theMessage" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

And it displays as the code and not the output desired. Any ideas on where I am going wrong? Is it on the xsl side or do I need CDATA in the database etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us exactly which XSLT processor you use, how you run the transformation, how you look at the transformation result. disable-output-escaping is not supported by all processors in all use cases, for instance Mozilla does not support it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#Can_I_do_disable-output-escaping.3F.

Comment: I figured it out, please see answer below. The output escaping was not the issue. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While output escaping has worked for me in the past, it did not do so on this string of data because the data contained ' marks which needed to be escaped.

so the string was as such (in java).

```
returnStr = returnStr.replace("'","\\'"); - this escaped those pesky tic marks, or single quotes
```

And the returnStr was equal to:`<style type="text/css">#container {width:100%; margin-top:20px; text-align:center; font-family: Verdana, arial; font-size:100%; font-weight:normal; }</style><div id="container"><b>Text here</b></div>`...plus a lot more html code and text

The xsl param was the same:

```
<xsl:param name="theMessage"></xsl:param>
```

And on the stylesheet the new code looked as such:

```
<div id="bilbo"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var outputString = '<xsl:value-of select="$theMessage" />'
    document.getElementById('bilbo').innerHTML = outputString;
    </script>
```

That pulled the data from the database, stripped out the single quotes, set the string to an xsl parameter, set the parameter to a js variable, then put it inside a div as the html it needed to be - as output.

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing in an element as a parameter, you will need to use **xsl:copy-of** rather than **xsl:value-of**

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$theMessage" />
```

All **xsl:value-of** will do is output the text of the element, not the element itself.