# xslt not transforming xml correctly in browser

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<item>
<title>Testing WebForm</title>
<link>http://linkurlhere.com</link>
<description>
<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary 
field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"     
property="content:encoded"><div style="background-color: white; width: 100%;">
<div id="prize" style="background-color: yellow; color: #660000; font-weight: 
bold; width: 200px;">Prize here</div>
</div>
<div id="startDate">Start Date: January 1, 2013</div>
<div id="endDate">End Date: January 1, 2014</div>
<p></p>
<p>Thanks for playing please take the survey - mock intro</p>
</div></div></div></description>
</item>
```

And I am rendering it with the following XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="rss/channel">
    <div id="surveyList">
        <p> Please
            click on the survey below and complete the survey.</p>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <div id="surveyItem">
                <div id="thePrize">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="description"  />
                </div>
                <a id="surveyLink">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="link"
                        disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="title">Click to complete this survey</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                </a>
                <br />
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rss/channel/item/description" name="description">
    <xsl:value-of select=".//div[@id='prize']" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

When I run this through an IDE such as Altova, and transform it, it shows up correctly with the div prize text. However, when I build out the webapp and deploy it either locally on tomcat 6.0 or on an actual webserver the prize does not show up, and it is not in the source when I view the page.

I have tried multiple browsers to no avail. Is this a simple setup problem with my XSLT page?

Thanks.

Updated below with complete XML including RSS elements:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://drupal-survey.url"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<channel>
 <title>drupal-survey.url</title>
 <link>http://drupal-survey.url</link>
 <description></description>
 <language>en</language>
<item>
 <title>Testing WebForm</title>
 <link>urlLink here</link>
 <description>
<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
<div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
<div style="background-color: white; width: 100%;">
<div id="prize" style="background-color: yellow; color: #660000; font-weight: bold; width: 200px;">$1000 Gift Card to McDonald&#039;s</div>
</div>
<div id="startDate">Start Date: January 1, 2013</div>
<div id="endDate">End Date: January 1, 2014</div>
<p>Thanks for playing please take the survey - mock intro</p>
</div></div></div></description>
<pubDate>Mon, 25 Feb 2013 19:12:48 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
<guid isPermaLink="false">6 at http://drupal-survey.url</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>sss162 test</title>
<link>http://drupal-survey.url/sss162/test</link>
<description><div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p>This is a testing paragraph</p>
<p>this is also</p>
</div></div></div></description>
<pubDate>Thu, 10 May 2012 19:24:43 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>sss162</dc:creator>
<guid isPermaLink="false">4 at http://drupal-survey.url</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>Orientation Survey</title>
<link>http://drupal-survey.url</link>
<description><div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
<div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><div id="startDate">Start Date: January 1, 2013</div>
<div id="endDate">End Date: January 1, 2014</div>
<p>This may be the brief explanation paragraph.</p>
</div></div></div></description>
<pubDate>Thu, 10 May 2012 17:11:38 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
<guid isPermaLink="false">2 at http://drupal-survey.url</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct XML? You XSLT is trying to select a **<document>** element, but no such element exists in your XML.

Comment: Fixed. Pasted wrong one.

Comment: Currently the link to the survey is displayed. not the prize text, at least in the browser.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the XML including the `rss` and `channel` elements?

Comment: @JLRishe added the complete xml

Comment: I don't see an `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` processing instruction in the sample XML. How are you telling the browser where to find the associated XSLT file? Have you verified that both the XML file and the XSLT file are accessible from your browser?

Comment: @JLRishe yes, I can get everything to render correctly except the section with the XPath related to the prize. The browser knows of both files. I am using a Jsp page to do all that. Like I said before, the correct rendering occurs within the IDE, however the section with the prize does not render in the browser....Like it doesn't care for my `<xsl:value-of select=".//div[@id='prize']" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` part, but everything else renders fine in the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSL disable-output-escaping not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164090/xsl-disable-output-escaping-not-working)